Finding all empty triangles of a plane
I have a set of $N$ points ${(x_i,y_i)}_{i=1,...,N}$. I am looking for an efficient algorithm to find the set of all empty triangles (i.e., that do not contain any points).
The brute-force method that I have so far is to identify all possible triangle (there are $N \choose 3$ combinations) and check if any of the $(N-3)$ remaining points are inside them. But this algorithm has a time complexity of $O(N^4)$ and is not very efficient.
I have an intuition that empty triangles necessarily belong to a triangulation of the plane and we know that triangulation algorithms can be very efficient, so maybe this could be a strategy. But even a triangulation algorithm cannot ensure to find all possible empty triangles. So maybe I have to find all possible triangulations? Although the set of all possible triangulations is potentially much larger than the set of all possible empty triangles and is not really what I am looking for here.
Any idea?
I am also wondering about the more general case: finding all possible empty simplices of a $d$-dimensional space.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249392/finding-all-empty-triangles
